# Multiple values in a alertbox xcode iphone dev

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to have multiple values showing in a alertbox but the last to pars dosnt seem to show, 
here is the code i have already,

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lose" message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Unlucky you only made it to       Level : %d" ,fred,@" and scored %i",score ] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Can anyone suggest a better way for this to behave?

Comment: Try Jeremy 1026's way, it should work. Another suggestion is, populate a string as your message body, use NSLog() to make sure it's the message you want, and then use it to populate your alert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lose" message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Unlucky you only made it to Level : %d  and scored %i",fred,score ] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```